# Self Hosting with Supabase - what are the next steps

Tags: self-hosting, supabase, supabase-database

I followed [this](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/hosting/docker) guide in the supabase docs to get started with self-hosting. The issue is that the information is very limited. After telling you how to run Docker, open localhost, and create API keys, there’s no more instructions. I’m extremely new to this, the only database I’ve worked with is Firebase which is much simpler, so I don’t know the next steps. Are there any full guides?

Comment: Judging from your questions, self-hosting might not be the best option for you. Since you've been using Firebase in the past, and are looking for a similar experience, you might be better off using the hosted service. Any reason you want to self host?

Comment: I am working on scaling my app which comes with a cost. Since I have the physical resources to self-host (huge drives and a good computer running debian 11), I figured I should try self-hosting to cut costs. The only reason I want to switch to Supabase is so I can self-host. I know my questions seem dumb but everyone starts somewhere and I just happen to have no prior knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCqta43JHkU
- https://dev.to/chronsyn/self-hosting-with-supabase-1aii
- https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-supabase-on-debian-11/amp/

I am going to try self-hosting next week, here are articles I found.

Comment: Interesting, I found the same ones. So far, the most helpful one has been the third. What I’m still not understanding is where the data is stored on Debian. Is it stored on the device it’s running on? Is it stored on the domain that points to it?

Comment: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml.  I think all data is stored on Debian through docker volume